# Force Locale in Windows Services

Tags: windows-server-2008, service, localization

I have some windows services running on an Windows 2008R2 server. My system locale on that server is English (US).

Is there any way you can force a windows services to use a specific locale (without changing the system locale)?

For example, services #1 I want to force it to use locale Japanese because it needs the Japanese locale to do the windows code page. Services #2 I want to force it to use Chinese (smplified).

Is this possibly without changing anything in windows services code?

I find some tips online about using a user account(that has a specific locale set) to run the windows service. I'm not sure how to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it the perfect way, ask the tool maker to handle a variable for you.

[setlocale, _wsetlocale](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d.aspx) is the Windows API to call in the service and/or program to change the local for the process.

- Sets or retrieves the run-time locale

Comment: You mean the services code need to accept a parameter as locale setting, that it passes locale to services code, which would call setlocale function to make sure services run in the specific locale? Thanks.

Comment: @rvpals Yes, it's what I mean, as I don't know any forced method when you run the .exe